# on server login page or registration page occur problem in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, server, config

Some important problems face in Codeigniter which I found and at last found the solution maybe it helps you so I share it.
 - Sometimes in CodeIgniter face a problem of login page redirection to the login page again.
 - On registration form when you fill the form and submit then it shows a null problem which error: 3014 or some type of error.
 - Mostly the session not working.

What is the solution

- there is lost of type solution and it depends on different scenarios.
- sometimes at $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data); at this point don't give underscore on logged_in will help.
- some times on application->config->config.php at $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; removeing the underscore from ci_session will help.
- And many other way to find your best solution. 
  And right now after facing a problem with my scenario and stucked for around 4 hours and searching lot's of pages and CodeIgniter form but didn't get any solution and then I realise maybe it's a version problem, mine was 3.1.3, so I updated it to 3.1.9. but the problem which I explain above which as same then after few more minute on spend on google but the problem was the same. Then suddenly one thing clicks on my mind and I applied that and boom all those problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which I applied on my case and it worked perfectly.
I memorise one thing.
on .htaccess I route my non www site to www.example.com but on

> config.php my base_url was example.com

and that is the problem wich occurs all those above problems on my website 
but when I change my

> example.com to www.example.com on base_url

everything comes on normal.
Maybe it also helps you.